# draw a pin in glass google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm using glass development kit, and I'm trying to show a pin.

Is there a google map sample ready to use ?to add my pin.
I saw I can use MapView if it was for an android app but with GDK it doesn't seems to work.

The position of the pin will be auto determinated by the network.

Answer (score 0):

[Static Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) is the thing you're looking for.
It allows you to embed a Google Maps image on your application.
You can easily download the content and apply it to an ImageView.

Google recently published a new [Google Maps Lite](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite) wich can be directly used as a fragment. (sample code included)

Both method will allow you to drop pins on the map, without using the original MapView.